# Molds associated with Aflatoxin?

Tags: microbiology, cancer, toxicology

I've been reading how some molds *may* be carcinogenic. In particular, molds associated with the fungus metabolite, [***Aflatoxin***](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aflatoxin).

Are the types of mold that produce this toxin, present in buildings/showers/domestic environments, **or** do they only grow on food-stuffs?

Comment: I've made a few linguistic changes. Also fungus is singular, fungi plural. Correct this in answer too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking the common bread mould *Rhizopus* sp. does not produce aflatoxin.
The fungus *Aspergillus flavus* which belongs to the class Ascomycetes secretes aflatoxin. It attacks cereal grains , legumes, tree nuts. The fungi are green in colour and 'mould' like in appearance.
The fungus attacks the food stuffs and storage grains. So under favourable conditions it may grow in your store room if it finds food for its growth. Also *Aspergillus* can grow at temperatures as high as 48°C and even at low temperatures like 5-8°C.

Edit: On being asked for sources I include some which strongly support my claim 
1. For suitable conditions of growth of the fungi visit https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspergillus_flavus and read under the Environment heading.
2. Visit https://bioweb.uwlax.edu/bio203/s2013/ernst_ale2/habitat.htm and read from " *Aspergillus flavus* is omnipresent " upto " Aspergillus may also grow on or inside walls in homes, especially if the house is damp or has been damaged by flooding. "
3.https://www.moldbacteria.com/mold-types.html this site provides a list of different fungi found in our homes. Here you can find Aspergillus flavus to grow in flower pot soil. Moreover other species of Aspergillus are found in kitchens and bathrooms.

Comment: So it is impossible for it to grow on walls?

Comment: I presume it cannot grow directly on walls unless it gets nutrition and moisture for its growth. Now if there is a damp wall the fundi may find some organic matter and may grow on it.

Comment: Sorry in the third line it is fungi

Comment: Including reliable citations within your answer to back-up your claims, is essential. Please consider adding the sources of the information you used, into your answer, as soon as you're able to. Thank you :)

Comment: For suitable conditions for the growth of the fungi see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspergillus_flavus and read under the Environment heading, next visit https://bioweb.uwlax.edu/bio203/s2013/ernst_ale2/habitat.htm and read from " Aspergillus flavus is omnipresent.....  " upto "Aspergillus may also grow on or inside walls in homes, especially if the house is damp or has been          
                                                   damaged by flooding. "

Comment: I have included some sources, check the answer for them.

Comment: This confuses me, showers are "damp". Does it or does it not grow in showers? Assuming there is no food in the bathroom.

Comment: also the reference is a student project. Some of its references are "mold removing sites" which I dont consider unbiased. I cant find any info on where and how it grows from the references in this student project. Let me know if you find something.

Comment: I will try to include more sources as soon as I find them. Moreover you can  think about this simple logic, the metal mouthpiece if your shower can hold water for a far less time than the cracks in walls or old air conditioners can , so naturally the fungi has more chances to grow in cracks of walls than in your shower.

Comment: https://www.moldbacteria.com/mold-types.html this site provides a list of different fungi found in your home. Here you can find Aspergillus flavus to grow in flower pot soil. Moreover other species of Aspergillus are found in kitchens and bathrooms.

Comment: Thats still not a research reference. Thanks alot for looking tho! This material has been to some help, and I can keep look from these places myself aswell. Its hard to dig for stuff like this without any academic traning in biology.
Let me know if you find somthing more rigorous btw!!